# What page version does SvelteKit return if SSR and Prerender are enabled for the page?

Tags: sveltekit

What page version will be returned to a client, if both SSR and Prerender options enabled for the page in SvelteKit?

Is there any reason to have both SSR and Prerender enabled for a route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly normal to have both enabled.

- [prerender](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#prerender) - whether the page should be generated at build time.
- [ssr](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#ssr) - whether the page component's HTML is in the generated page

So if you have the following `+page.svelte`...

```html
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
```

... setting `export const prerender = true` will generate a `index.html` file at build time. If SSR is enabled (which is the default), then that `index.html` will contain the `<h1>` tag present in the page - the `+page.svelte` component was rendered on the server and the output was placed into the prerendered `index.html` file. If SSR is disabled with `export const ssr = false`, then the generated HTML will be an empty shell and the `<h1>` will be rendered on the page via client-side JavaScript.

The shell might look something like this. Note that there is no `<h1>` - when the user visits the page, they will have to wait for the client-side JavaScript to run and insert the `<h1>` into the page.

```html
<head>a bunch of link tags showing which stylesheets to load</head>
<body>
<div></div>
<script src="/wherever/the/built/scripts/are"></script>
</body>
```

With `prerender` enabled, the user will be served a static HTML page when they visit the website, instead of needing to run code on a server to generate the page. However, the content of that page will be different depending on if `ssr` was enabled at build time.

In general, SvelteKit recommends keeping [SSR enabled](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/glossary#ssr):

> Server-side rendering (SSR) is the generation of the page contents on the server. SSR is generally preferred for SEO. While some search engines can index content that is dynamically generated on the client-side it may take longer even in these cases. It also tends to improve perceived performance and makes your app accessible to users if JavaScript fails or is disabled (which happens more often than you probably think).

Comment: Are these assumptions correct?

1) if SSR is disabled, then Prerender(true or false) itself doesn't make any difference, since all rendering happens on client side only

2) if SSR is enabled:
2.a) if Prerender is enabled, then prerendered at built time page will be returned to a client
2.b) if Prerender is disabled, then server dynamically renders the page and sends over to a client

Comment: Assumption #2 is correct. #1 is almost correct - with SSR disabled, the page served will be identical whether or not prerendering is enabled. However, if prerendering is disabled, then your server will still have to run on each request just to generate an empty page, which is wasteful.

Comment: Although if `ssr` is `false` at the top level, setting `prerender` to `false` will only cause the server to generate the empty shell on the first page request per user session. Subsequent navigation won't go to the server to regenerate the shell. They'll just fetch the new contents. So setting both options to `false` isn't quite as wasteful as it first sounds.

Comment: @GeoffRich with export const prerender=true only my build passes since m using adapter-static, when i check html files it has bunch of js as modulepreload. does it mean its going to take this js and build page on client side? since there is no html content in these html file. or it is like this for dynamically loaded routes